# Get outer object pointer inside inner object

Tags: c++, offset, pointer-to-member

There are two objects: `Holder` and `Property`. `Holder` contains `Property` as a field. I want to get access to `Holder` from `Property`. In general case the address of `Property` will be address of `Holder` + offset of field of type `Property`.

**But important**: the `Property` should not have any fields (for example I can't pass the `Holder` to constructor of `Property` and save it as 'outer').

*UPD: I suppose this trick should only work for the standard layout.*

*UPD2: The main reason why I want to use such approach (do not pass reference to `Property`) is use minimum memory as possible in `Holder` object. In best case: `sizeof(Property)` is 0 bytes (Although the standard does not allow this).*

First that I tried to do is pass pointer to member to template parameter:

```
Property<&Holder::prop> prop;
```

or

```
Property<offsetof(Holder, prop)> prop;
```

But `prop` is not defined yet (it is error).

Full pseudocode will looks like this:

```
template<size_t FieldOffset>
class Property
{
    class Holder* GetOuter()
    {
           return (char*)this - FieldOffset;  // go to Outer object via offset of our field
    }
}

class Holder
{
    int Field1;
    std::string Field2;
    Property<offsetof(Holder, prop)> prop;  // Error!
}
```

Are there any other suggestions to do something similar?

Comment: Why are you subtracting from a pointer? That seems like trouble. Your assumptions about the memory layout are liable to be incorrect.

Comment: Pass a reference to the outer class to the constructor of the inner class. Do not make assumptions on the memory layouts and where you can find them. So Holder needs to get an extra member referring to the outer class. So just `Property& parent` and a constructor `explicit Holder(Property& parent)`. (Assuming the property has a longer lifecycle then holder here)

Comment: If you need to navigate from one object to another via pointers, pass that pointer down during construction. Don't make assumptions about how things are ordered, arranged, or allocated. The only way to be *sure* you've got the right pointer is if C++ gives it to you, not if you try and divine it through some dark ritual.

Comment: Tip: Is this a shared property that would best be encapsulated as a reference? In something like `std::shared_ptr`? Is it something where both will potentially mutate it?

Comment: If you want to avoid the reference to parent at any price (what are the reasons for, by the way? – I do not see why you shouldn't (want to) go that way, so sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) you still could pass the parent to any operation (i.e. function) of the property.

Comment: A working [mcve] which just gives `Holder*` pointer to `Property` constructor would be nice, to demonstrate how you are going to use this. As I understand it, you want this, but without needing to pass `this` to `Holder::prop` constructor. Maybe there is another way, but that's hard to say without seeing actual example.

Comment: It's been my experience over the years that when you need to do this, there's usually a better solution to the original problem.

Comment: @hyde https://godbolt.org/z/eGWarjWbM 
For example Property pattern, but I want to avoid memory allocation for Property object.

Comment: @ArtemSelivanov Are you aware that minimum size of an object in C++ is 1, even if it is empty? So there will be a memory allocation, if there is a member object. I don't think it can be optimized away, though I can be wrong here. Of course 1 is less than size of a pointer, but aligning may still result in it requiring more than 1 byte of size in a class.

Comment: @hyde https://godbolt.org/z/fYYhKoj3x
As minimum as possible. Anyway 1 is better than pointer size

Comment: Maybe you could use a char to store offset, as an alternative to storing full pointer... Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

The memory model in C++ allows navigation from a member subobject to its containing (class-type) object only when the class is **standard-layout** and the member is the **first** member.  The idea is that compilers can reason about which pointers have to **escape** for a write to necessitate reloading some other value from memory.  As such, what you want is **impossible** in almost all cases, although there have been [proposals](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0149r0.pdf) to relax that rule so as to add features like this one.